# JDK and Maven Confliction

Tags: maven, classpath, java, javac

I am using Eclipse Juno integrated with maven plugin.

I have installed JDK 1.6 on my system.

**My environment variables are**

```
JAVA_HOME - F:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37

MAVEN_HOME - F:\apache-maven-3.0.4

classpath - ;.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;

Path - C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;.;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;
```

My JDK and JRE are working smooth.

**Command Line Check :** [image: Command Line Check]

In my eclipse I am building a new maven web project which should give me a war file.

**My pom.xml :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.achutha.labs</groupId>
  <artifactId>01JsfExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>01JsfExample</name>


  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I do maven clean, its a success.
But when i do maven install it is giving some jdk issues.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building 01JsfExample 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ 01JsfExample ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ 01JsfExample ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to F:\Workspace\01JsfExample\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  F:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.554s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 10 06:54:01 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project 01JsfExample: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] F:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My other java programs on eclipse are compiling and running fine.
Except for maven projects. The war file is not getting generated as build is failure due to the above reason.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Get a JDK installed on that system. Right now it appears you only have the JRE.

Comment: write in your console `set JAVA`. this will show you your JAVA_HOME, looks like it points to JRE instead of JDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running Maven goals in Eclipse? If so, it looks like Eclipse is trying to access the JRE as opposed to the JDK: `F:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar`

Although `JAVA_HOME` seems to be set correctly at the Windows level, it could be that in Eclipse you're running the app with a JRE, not a JDK. In Eclipse, have a look at the installed JREs list (Window ->  Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs). If you don't have a JDK, click on 'Edit' after selecting the JRE and in that dialog box enter the location to the JDK.

Comment: I don't believe Eclipse cares about the value of JAVA_HOME, since you can set multiple JREs and JDKs.

Comment: You're right, @tom . What I meant is that even though JAVA_HOME might be fine at the Windows level, JDK/JREs are defined by different means in Eclipse. I should probably rephrase that sentence in my answer

Comment: @junal flores...
Your guess was correct.
It was pointing to other JRE and not the one in jdk folder.
Thanks for the solution.
It was very much effective.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to use maven install option from eclipse. Try mvn install from command line. If that fails the issue is with java setup ( installation, path, variable ). Recheck whether your java home is correctly pointing to jdk and not jre. Also ensure eclipse javaw.exe from jdk bin directory.

If cmd line install works then issue is with eclipse java configuration for your maven project. You can try resolving it by -

1. You should verify the project properties set up in eclipse to ensure the java runtime is the correct one.
2. You should verify in the project facet the java compilation is set to 1.6
3. You should set java compilation information in pom.xml sourcejdk and targetjdk tags.

Comment: the problem was in eclipse, it had taken a wrong JRE and not the JRE in JDK.
Thanks for the answer.